# How to pass current URL to mailto body

Tags: php, email, url

I have problem with passing url into mail body. I have use this:

```
<?php
function CurrentPageURL()
{
$pageURL = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$pageURL .= $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != '80' ? $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER
["REQUEST_URI"] : $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
return $pageURL;
}
?>
```

and `mailto:?body=<?php echo CurrentPageURL(); ?>`

Instead of this link as result:
http://www.something.com/index.php?id=03new&new=50&lang=en

I get this one in mail body:
http://www.something.com/index.php?id=03new

Please help me how to pass all link including "&".

Thx

Comment: Does [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) help you any?

Comment: You need to `urlencode()` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'&' is used in mailto to separate different parts like:

`&subject=some_subject&body=message_body`

So will be interpreted as an (invalid) parameter for the mailto (and omitted). So if you want to have '&' (and the rest of url) inside the body, it needs to be replaced with their % value. Using a function like `urlencode()` will do the job.

```
<?php
function CurrentPageURL()
{
...
return urlencode($pageURL);
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you expand on why this solution might solve the question?

Comment: @Denomales: '&' is used in mailto to separate different parts like &subject=some_subject&body=message_body so if you want to have '&' inside the body it needs to be replaced with their % value and urlencode() does the job.